# why finding the second closest object sometime return null?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to find the closest and second closest object by using the code below. However there is a little bug while I was using it. When the player move away from the second closest object sometime the result return null. Anyone know what causing this? I have included the debug.drawline picture as well which shows the problem.

[image]

[image]

```
    public GameObject[] FindClosestEnemy()
    {
        GameObject[] gos;
        gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Agents");
        GameObject closest = null;
        GameObject secondClosest = null;
        float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
        Vector2 position = transform.position;
        foreach (GameObject go in gos)
        {
            Vector2 diff = (Vector2)go.transform.position - position;

            float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
            if (curDistance < distance)
            {
                secondClosest = closest;
                closest = go;
                distance = curDistance;
            }
        }

        Debug.DrawLine(position, closest.transform.position);
        Debug.DrawLine(position, secondClosest.transform.position);

        Debug.Log("1" + "and" + closest);
        Debug.Log("2" + "two" + secondClosest);
        //Debug.Log(gos[1]);

        return new GameObject[] { closest, secondClosest };
    }
```

Comment: theres cases where you dont assign `secondClosest`

Comment: I've updated my answer, James.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `secondClosest` to be `null` here

`GameObject secondClosest = null;`

and later have logic that **conditionally** assigns `secondClosest`

```
if (curDistance < distance)
{
   secondClosest = closest;
   closest = go;
   distance = curDistance;
}
```

So if your condition does not hold, then `secondClosest` remains `null` as you initialized.

If the condition does hold, you assigned `secondClosest` to point to whatever `closest` is pointing to, which is currently `null`. You **later** try to assign `closest = go`, but that changes where `closest` points to, not `secondClosest`, which still points to a null reference. Here's an example with arrays:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/BafOSW

Comment: I understand that point, but is there anyway to keep closest and secondClosest value at the same time ? @8protons from the joll05 ans it seems I need to edit some part of the condition which honestly I still have no clue. because I need the red triangle to keep searching for the secondclosest object to find the new target every time it collide with the previous target.

Comment: Are you asking me what your new condition should be or how to make `secondClosest` and `closest` the same?

Comment: I believe the underlining issue is because the condition since it gave me the correct value at this stage?

Comment: @James Well firstly you should handle the fact that there IS a case where `curDistance` >= distance`, and so `closest` and `secondClosest` will be null, causing an exception.  You also are iterating in your foreach but it looks like after the foreach, you only do something to `closest` and `secondClosest` one time. Is that really what you want to happen?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, if an enemy is further away than the current closest enemy it will be ignored completely. Therefore, if the closest enemy comes before the second closest in the array you get from `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Agents")` then the second closest enemy won't be correct.